# Does signing a message as specified in AOPP incur a fee?

Tags: transaction-fees, signature

Does signing a message as specified in [Address Ownership Proof Protocol](https://gitlab.com/aopp/address-ownership-proof-protocol/-/blob/master/README.md) (AOPP) incur a fee? I think not - there is nothing written in the specification about broadcasting
anything to the Bitcoin blockchain. Am I correct assuming that such proof of ownership does not incur a fee?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transaction fee is a bid for the transaction to get included in a block. Since signed messages are only transferred out of band directly to the recipient of the message, they do not incur a fee.